Get a hash from XML
I need to get the same hash of an xml in any language.
I tried to get the xml's canonical form then get it's hash
But what I experienced was that the canonical is not a "fixed standard". It is implemented in different forms by all the libs and languages that I worked with... so, I never get the SAME hash.
So, my question is: is there a way to get a trustable hash of the same canonical XML?
Edit
I'm using this xml as example:
<doc xmlns="http://www.ietf.org" xmlns:w3c="http://www.w3.org" xml:base="something/else">
   <e1>
      <e2 xmlns="" xml:id="abc" xml:base="bar/">
         <e3 id="E3" xml:base="foo"/>
      </e2>
   </e1>
</doc>

To get the Canonical Form, I've used:
In c# (.net version 8):

Lib System.Security.Cryptography.Xml (version 8.0.0)

string stringXml = "<doc xmlns=\"http://www.ietf.org\" xmlns:w3c=\"http://www.w3.org\" xml:base=\"something/else\">\n   <e1>\n      <e2 xmlns=\"\" xml:id=\"abc\" xml:base=\"bar/\">\n         <e3 id=\"E3\" xml:base=\"foo\"/>\n      </e2>\n   </e1>\n</doc>";

System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.XmlDsigC14NWithCommentsTransform c14n = new();

System.Xml.XmlDocument documentXml = new();
documentXml.LoadXml(stringXml);
c14n.LoadInput(documentXml);

Stream stream = (Stream)c14n.GetOutput(typeof(Stream));
string result = new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();

using var hash = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256.Create();
var byteArray = hash.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
string sha256hex = Convert.ToHexString(byteArray);

Console.WriteLine(sha256hex);


The sha256hex result was:

4716238DE66819B69981AE1BD3943451D0EADEEA001583D27CDFDC4255484CB6


The canonicalized result was:

<doc xmlns="http://www.ietf.org" xmlns:w3c="http://www.w3.org" xml:base="something/else"><e1><e2 xmlns="" xml:base="bar/" xml:id="abc"><e3 id="E3" xml:base="foo"></e3></e2></e1></doc>

In java (version 21):

Lib org.apache.santuario xmlsec (version 4.0.2)

And Lib commons-codec (version 1.17.0) (just for hashing)


String stringXml= "<doc xmlns=\"http://www.ietf.org\" xmlns:w3c=\"http://www.w3.org\" xml:base=\"something/else\">\n   <e1>\n      <e2 xmlns=\"\" xml:id=\"abc\" xml:base=\"bar/\">\n         <e3 id=\"E3\" xml:base=\"foo\"/>\n      </e2>\n   </e1>\n</doc>";

org.apache.xml.security.Init.init();
org.apache.xml.security.c14n.Canonicalizer c14n = org.apache.xml.security.c14n.Canonicalizer.getInstance(org.apache.xml.security.c14n.Canonicalizer.ALGO_ID_C14N_WITH_COMMENTS);

java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
c14n.canonicalize(stringXml.getBytes(), stream, false);
String result = stream.toString(java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String sha256hex = org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha256Hex(result);
System.out.println(sha256hex);


The sha256hex result was:

dea874fbbe21f9e27e521cfddf61aa54bc1b0b18692e3105455eeca24beea1f6


The canonicalized result was:

<doc xmlns="http://www.ietf.org" xmlns:w3c="http://www.w3.org" xml:base="something/else">
   <e1>
      <e2 xmlns="" xml:base="bar/" xml:id="abc">
         <e3 id="E3" xml:base="foo"></e3>
      </e2>
   </e1>
</doc>


This is an interesting question. Canonical XML, on it surface, seems like it should eliminate inconsistencies, like white-space differences. Have you tried opening the two XML files in a diff tool to see what the differences are? Even differences in line endings could doom a trustable hash of the two files.

And <![CDATA[ islands could be another point of contention.

The wikipedia article about canonical XML states that, *"According to the W3C, if two XML documents have the same canonical form, then the two documents are logically equivalent within the given application context (except for limitations regarding a few unusual cases)." I wonder if you just happen to be experiencing one of these "unusual cases"?

I don't know if you can get the same hash when you have two different libs generating the canonical form. You might need to know which lib generated the canonical forms and use the same lib to compare them by regenerating the hash? The answer might be to simply use your own chosen lib to take two non-canonical XML files, generate a canonical version of each and then hash those outputs.

Thanks for your comment! Yeah! I've tried! One of the 2 tests that I made was a "clean" (no unnecessary white-spaces) single line. The other one had multiple lines, tabs, and unnecessary white-spaces.

Yeah, it is probably an unusual case (LoL). The problem is that the c# has one lib and java has another one. So... each of them uses one "interpretation" of the W3C standard.

Honestly, that's the problem. You need to use the same lib to generate the canonical form - and quite possibly the same version.

Fair enough... well, I will try to get this hash in some other way then... Thanks a lot!

It would be helpful if you could be more precise. Please show us an input document that is canonicalized differently by Java and C#, and show us exactly how you invoked the canonicalization process in each case. They SHOULD produce exactly the same output, byte for byte, and if they don't, then we should be able to find out why.

Alright! I'll update my question...

I've updated the question with my code and my results!

I'd just like to say that this demonstrates the outrageous complexity of XML.  In any other data format, the canonical format is the canonical format.  There's exactly one, and everybody does it the same.  With XML, even using the same algorithm, C14N, algorithms still find ambiguity.

@gdonega, logical equivalence of two XML documents does not need to imply identical byte streams. Compare the canonicalized string that you feed into the hash algorithm and see if you can explain the differences in the byte stream. Be also on the lookout for things like a byte-order mark at the start of the byte stream.

In this case, the differences are break-lines, unnecessary whitespace, etc.
The logical equivalence is correct.

@gdonega I would suggest trying a couple things: 1. print out the canonical forms and look for differences. 2. Strip out all unnecessary whitespace.

I just looked at the canonical spec and it does consider any whitespace within an element to be significant.  That means all the line endings and well as indentation in your example doc.  I see in the comments history that you tried stripping it out (sorry missed that before) but my experience says you should always do that.

I could have missed something but the only thing that I would expect to change when you canonicalize that document is that the <e3> element will be changed to: <e3 id="E3" xml:base="foo"></e3> See here.

Ohh! I see! That DOES make a lot of sense! And I can see why c# keeps the whitespace! Thanks for the explanation!

@gdonega Sorry, did you see differences in the canonical output?  If so, it would be helpful to future readers to show that.

I've updated with the canonicalized result!

Your problem is that in the C# code, prior to canonicalization, you parsed the XML document with a parser that strips whitespace, whereas in Java, you preserved the whitespace. In general whitespace in XML is significant, though of course in some particular document types it isn't. You need to decide whether to strip whitespace prior to canonicalization or not; you will get different signatures (and different canonicalizations) depending on whether you strip it or not.
With C#, to avoid stripping whitespace, set the PreserveWhitespace property on the XmlDocument.
If instead you want to add whitespace stripping to the Java code, the simplest way is to run a simple XSLT transformation:
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
</xsl:transform>


Thanks for your answer! I've tried your PreserveWhitespace solution, and I've experienced that even then the results were different. What did the trick (in my case) was to execute the regex "\W" (removing them) and then get the hash. It resolved my problems.

In both your C# and Java code, you are simply hashing the byte sequence contained in the string variable result. This will only yield the same hash value if both strings are byte for byte identical. Even a 1-bit difference in the two strings will produce completely different hash values. So you canonicalization procedure has to produce identical strings to give the same hash.
To diagnose the issue, save the string result to a file and compare with some sort of file comparison utility (Beyond Compare, WinDiff or even the CMD prompt's fc).

I recently was writing a program that had to generate some XML documents that were binary identical to those produced by a commercial program.  So I went through a lot of iterations of Beyond Compare.  And I encountered a lot of WTFs by the commercial product with things like one part of the XML preferring  for empty tags, while other parts of the document preferring .

@PeterM That's exactly the problem that canonical XML aims to solve.
